# Does the AT-AT type ocean crane walker in The Mandalorian S2E3 have a model name?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In S2E3 of The Mandalorian, the Razor Crest misses a landing pad on Trask and has to be lifted out of the water by this walker.

[image: Trask Walker lifting the Razor Crest out of the water.]

Does this walker have a class/model name? Has anything similar (industrial use of a walker) shown up in canon (or extended canon) before?

[This ScreenRant article](https://screenrant.com/mandalorian-season-2-new-atat-water-complaint-fix/) seems to say it is a modified AT-AT, however this seems more to just be speculation and the entire body of the vehicle seems far too different from an AT-AT for it to just be modified, so in my opinion it is more likely to have been mass produced for industrial purposes.

Comment: Similar to the https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/OI-CT

Comment: We just call him Little Bobby Lifty Big Things.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Trask_walker

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Does this walker have a class/model name? - **No official name.**

Has anything similar (industrial use of a walker) shown up in canon (or extended canon) before? - **Yes, the OI-CT.**

---

We do see something very similar known as the [OI-CT](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/OI-CT) appear in *Solo: A Star Wars Story* on Corellia.

[image: Screenshot of an OI-CT in Solo: A Star Wars Story walking in the water]

This screen shot comes from an official Star Wars Kids video, ["Every Surface Vehicle in Star Wars Movies | Star Wars By the Numbers"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7dVRY2QRV0) in which the walker was first named.

The video was released in March 2019 over a year before the other walker appears in *The Mandalorian*. So the walker you ask about *could* be a modified OI-CT or something else entirely...

Answer (score 7):

**Per the official audio description for the episode, it's a '*mobile loading gantry*'**

> *"A cargo sling at the end of a crane lifts the Razor Crest out of the water, tossing its occupants around in the cockpit. An enormous, four-legged **mobile loading gantry** swings the shop towards the wharf and drops it unceremoniously onto the nearest berth, covered in seaweed"*

And referred to in the [*The Art of Star Wars: The Mandalorian (Season Two)*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Star_Wars:_The_Mandalorian_(Season_Two)) as simply

> "***Trask Walker***"

and

> "***Trask Dock Walker***"

[image]